# Complex String Operation in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a string `abc@123 (hello world) posted 23 July 1990 20:34:00 +000`. I want output as `hello world abc (abc@123) posted "on" 23 July 1990 "at" 20:34:00` Should it be done with explode or preg() function??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a regex with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace), here is an example that can likely be improved upon:

```
$str = 'abc@123 (hello world) posted 23 July 1990 20:34:00 +000';
echo preg_replace( '/([A-Za-z]+)@(\d+) \(([A-Za-z ]+)\) posted (\d+ [A-Za-z]+ \d+) (\d+:\d+:\d+) .*/', '$3 $1 ($1@$2) posted "on" $4 "at" $5', $str);
```

Output:

> hello world abc (abc@123) posted "on" 23 July 1990 "at" 20:34:00

[Demo](http://codepad.org/QHhGurVj)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all strings are the same format, I would suggest using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).